# Gerenciamento de erro do flask fazendo loop e não redirecionando

Tags: python-3.x, http, flask

Configurei um servidor que pode enviar e receber arquivos, com um limite de tamanho de 50mb usando `['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] =  50 * 1024 * 1024`, também fiz um ErroHandler pro erro 413, que é o que eu recebo quando envio um arquivo grande.
Mas quando ele recebe o arquivo grande, o servidor joga o usuário num loop 3 vezes, e depois o navegador mostra um erro de `ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`.

Tentei usando "`413`" no @app, "`RequestEntityTooLarge`", ambos e não muda nada. Tentei também o return só com uma mensagem e o erro, só uma mensagem, um flash e depois redirecionar de volta pra página ou pra home, e nada mudou. O Handler é executado, porém não faz nada que eu digo pra fazer, só piora o problema.

**Erro:**

```
Não é possível acessar esse site
A página (papapa)/upload pode estar temporariamente indisponível ou pode ter sido movida permanentemente para um novo endereço da Web.
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

**Upload:**

```
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            f = form.f.data
            path = 'files/.'
            files = os.listdir(path)

            if f.filename not in files:
                filesPath = 'files/'
                f.save(filesPath + secure_filename(f.filename))
                flash('O arquivo foi enviado.')
                return render_template('upload.html', form = form)

            elif f.filename in files:
                flash('Esse nome já foi usado.')
                return render_template('upload.html', form = form)
        except:
            print(sys.exc_info()[0])
            flash('Algo deu errado ao enviar seu arquivo.')
            return redirect(request.url)

    return render_template('upload.html', form = form)
```

**ErroHandler:**

```
@app.errorhandler(413) #tentei RenquestEntityTooLarge
def error_413(e):
    flash('Seu arquivo é grande demais. Max: 50mb')
    return redirect(url_for('upload'))
```

**Saida do terminal:**

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 302 -
POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 302 -
POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Já tentei também usar `time.sleep(1)` pra dar tempo do navegador carregar.
Por que ele faz um loop e como eu faço pra ele redirecionar depois de um erro?

**Edit1:** Descobri que funciona no celular, porém não funciona em nenhum computador, nem mesmo em uma maquina virtual usando Hamachi. Não pode ser cache ou cookie ja que a modificação é do servidor, e não estou usando nenhum cookie.

Comment: Basicamente, tenho o mesmo problema [desse cara](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/8768zv/issue_with_setting_max_content_length_for_file/). E sim, estou usando outro computador para testes, não é problema de estar testando no host

Comment: Por algum motivo quando coloco que o maximo é de apenas 50 bytes não acontece nenhum erro

Comment: dependendo do arquivo, ele faz oq eu quero, ou não